# iOS: UITapGestureRecognizer in Static TableViewController. PrepareForSegue not called

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have static TableViewController with PrepareForSegue in each cell. I have not problem until I added a new cell with textField included. For dismissing Keyboard i added UITapGestureRecognizer in viewDidLoad. After adding this TapGesture the singleSelection in Cell not working anymore. Is there a specific reason?

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            addressTextField.delegate=self

            let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TableViewController.dismissKeyboard))
            view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }


      func dismissKeyboard() {
            view.endEditing(true)
        }


     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if segue.identifier == "LinkToRegion" {
                let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! RegionTableViewController
                viewController.parameter = regionLabel.text
                viewController.delegate=self
            }
            if segue.identifier == "LinkToProv" {
                let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ProvTableViewController
                viewController.parameter = provLabel.text
                viewController.delegate=self
            }
            if segue.identifier == "LinkToCity" {
                let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CityTableViewController
                viewController.cities = cities
                viewController.parameter = cityLabel.text
                viewController.delegate=self
            }
            if segue.identifier == "LinkToInvia" {
                let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! InviaViewController
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` recognizer to the `view`, the view will intercept the touch events and your table view cells will never receive them. Hence why they will never show selection.

One solution would be to add the tap gesture recognizer only when the text field has focus and then remove it on dismissal

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the storyboard. On the tableView elements, under keyboard, just set: "Dismiss on drag".